# Inference of generic type argument of class fails depending on properties on that class

Tags: typescript

I have a fairly simple case where Typescript doesn't infer the types. I'd like to know why Typescript behaves this way.

## Case where Typescript type inference fails

If you have the following classes declarations:

```js
declare class Swine
{
    grunt(): void
}

declare abstract class Part<T> {}

declare class Hoof extends Part<Swine> {}
```

And the following function:

```js
declare function getOwner<T>(part: Part<T>): T;
```

Then the following code fails in the Typescript compiler:

```js
getOwner(new Hoof())
  .grunt();
```

This is because Typescript infers the return type of getOwner to be `unknown`, instead of `Swine`.

## The strange but effective solution

If I merely add a property `animal: T` to the declaration of `Part`, though, **the code will start to will work**.

So in other words, if the declaration of `Part` becomes:

```js
declare abstract class Part<T>
{
  animal: T
}
```

Typescript will be able to infer the return type of `getOwner(new Hoof())`. I have verified this behavior for Typescript 3.9.7 and 4.1.3.

## Question

Why does Typescript behave this way? Should it not keep the generic type information, even when the `T` does not occur in any of the class members' signatures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the TypeScript FAQ entry on unused type parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--) for a canonical answer.

TypeScript's type system is largely *structural* and not *nominal*.  That means if you are comparing type `A` and `B`, they are considered to be the same type if and only if they have the same *structure* (e.g., both are object types with members of the same keys and same value types).  It does not matter what types `A` and `B` are *named* (e.g., the fact that I use names like "`A`" and "`B`" isn't relevant) or where they are *declared* (e.g., having separate declarations like `interface A { a: string }` and `interface B { a: string }` doesn't make them separate types).

---

In particular, given the declaration

```
declare abstract class Part<T> { }
```

You can see that no matter what type you specify for `T`, the resulting type is an empty object type with no members, and therefore is the same type as just `{}`.  The compiler really doesn't see any difference between `Part<swine>` and `Part<string>` or anything else.

To see this, note that TypeScript will not let you redeclare a `var` with a type annotation of a different type from the original declaration:

```
var bad: Swine;
var bad: string; // error!
//  ~~~
//  Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.
```

But none of the following yields any compiler error:

```
var okay: Part<Swine>;
var okay: {}; // no error
var okay: Part<string>; // no error
var okay: Part<unknown>; // no error
```

So they really *are* the same type in TypeScript.  And that means when you hand the compiler a value of type `Part<Swine>`, there's nothing `Swine`-like about it.  The name `Part<Swine>` is just a *name*, and should no bearing on how the compiler processes the type.  Trying to infer `T` from a value of type `Part<T>` is therefore impossible in principle; the inference fails, and you get `unknown`.

Adding a property of type `T` to `Part<T>` changes everything.  Now there is a
*structural* difference between `Part<Swine>` and `Part<string>` or `Part<unknown>` or `{}`, and the compiler has a handle on which to determine `T` from `Part<T>`.

---

If we imagine taking this down from the type level into the value level by looking at functions that take string representations of types and turns them into other string representations of types, the analog of what you were doing is something like this:

```
function part(T: string): string {
  return "{}";
}
const hoof = part("Swine");
function getOwnerType(partT: string): string {
  // how would you implement this ???
  return "unknown";
}
console.log(getOwnerType(hoof)); // unknown
```

The translation of `declare abstract class Part<T> {}` is just `(T: string) => "{}"`).  Since `part("Swine")` produces the same output as `part("string"}` or anything else, namely the string `"{}"`, there's no way to write the reverse function `getOwnerType()`. If, on the other hand, your `part()` function has an output that actually depends on its input, things become more reasonable:

```
function part(T: string): string {
  return "{animal: " + T + "}";
}
const hoof = part("Swine");
function getOwnerType(partT: string): string {
  return (partT.match(/^{animal: (.*)}$/) ?? ["", "unknown"])[1];
}
console.log(getOwnerType(hoof)); // Swine
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwMoHcCWA7BA3gFDzwDmMArrgC4AUAlAFzwBuA9tsEQL5FGgkceFABGyGjChgaiaKngAFWDQA8AFQB88AvD5FWseKKjAWWPCADcBoybPwJMPGSvwA9O-ggYMdjABCIk9SAD9w4K8MSnEQAEdKEFo2WGwxCARBaCkabHZcNABbSgl4AAsoVgQaMoRkKELqgE8ABxAAOn5DGHh2AGsoJpZlGDULfE0bbt6BoZ0eNxDcdm9ff1se-sHhlVUnF0mPL2XVvxgNme2lXeo+5cxcQ6WVnzP+LNgEJAUACXZ2ABm3gAHjQksA0CMxjgJjo9PwiMRSEjSPAAdQZHlcPAWio6OoWPtcGRmI5JC4dCRUaQ4DRKDBsQAiAg8Rk2al8algfKlMr-IEAXhxeMZ4xAjIY7NR6NwmPy5BANAA8g8fOpWiA6LjRgSyc5iaSiWRKdTSCE+Zh4Jh2JQIMB4E0bfBsIUWhlGskatg0AB+P1U6m0+lM273XBsgPwrk89gZdoQdhkOhkRUq-AwdVtOh8wEMSVHeCh9gPKmcymRmVy7Ha+i6o2G8nEk2moMM+DMqC4F1QCAsRnwADU8HUg-brKlpDLpG5BVkOcFwtGdFFMPFkorGNy8pTytVGY1WpUdcbJMJJ+bgcVwfgh517UKUBoYDKdHcAD0CJ3u72b+0AFQMDwAAk7gMPAfrwAA2oyjIADTtkWDyMgAugwkEAIzIROUaojOyCxh0CZJjuaZqge855osXhivwk68O84DZAglZbtiJF7homi3jQOyjJxpLqDYRDsemdD4JafyAowDBUu0FDUPQ65AA)