# How to set a property type to textable representation of Type name in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, template-literals

Say, I have these class & interface:

```js
class Foo {}
interface Bar {}
```

I want to create such a `type` that has a property name of a specified type:

```js
type DynamicPropertyName<T> = ... <-- ???
```

Then I want to use it like so:

```js
type WithPropFoo = DynamicPropertyName<Foo>; // desire: {Foo: any}
type WithPropBar = DynamicPropertyName<Bar>; // desire: {Bar: any}
```

Instead of `any`, I will specify my type, that's easy.

#### UPD after 3rd comment

At least, maybe it is possible to get this:

```js
type WithPropFoo = DynamicPropertyName<Foo>; // desire: {type: 'Foo'}
type WithPropBar = DynamicPropertyName<Bar>; // desire: {type: 'Bar'}

const foo: WithPropFoo = {type: 'Foo'};   // ok
const foo: WithPropFoo = {type: 'Hello'}; // error

const foo: WithPropBar = {type: 'Bar'};   // ok
const foo: WithPropBar = {type: 'Hello'}; // error
```

Comment: I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64933956 helpful. @jcalz maybe you could add anything? =)

Comment: It's kind of sad that I'm here so much that I saw this, even though @-mentioning people not directly involved with a question doesn't do anything.  Anyway, no, there's no programmatic way to convert the *name* of a type into a corresponding string literal.  It's possible to get `"Foo"` at runtime but not at compile time (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48438666/typescript-get-class-name-in-its-own-property-at-compile-time)) but `"Bar"` is completely inaccessible.  You will need to put these strings somewhere yourself if you want them.

Comment: Type names are essentially unobservable. TypeScript has a structural, not nominal type system. If you write `interface A {x: 0}` and `interface B {x: 0}` then type `A` and type `B` are the same type despite having different declarations. In principle then, you shouldn't be able to perform a type operation `F<A>` and `F<B>` and have two different outputs. If this makes sense and you're okay with "no, sorry" I can write up an answer. If you are really trying to do something else and this was how you thought to do it, it might be an XY problem and you should detail the intended use case instead.

Comment: @jcalz please, look at UPD. Whether that is possible or not, you can write an answer if you like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but this is impossible in TypeScript.

---

Interface names like `Bar` are, in principle, *unobservable*.  It's hard to find an authortitative source for this, but if you consult [this comment on Microsoft/TypeScript#3060](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3060#issuecomment-110095960) and maybe  [this comment on Microsoft/TypeScript#3628](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3628#issuecomment-145986726), you'll see some related information and reasoning.

TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and not [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system).  That means if two types `A` and `B` have the same *structure*, then they are the same *type*.  It doesn't matter if they have different *names* or *declarations*.  For example:

```
interface A {x: string}
interface B {x: string}
const c = {x: "hello"};
// const c: { x: string; } 

function acceptA(a: A) {}
acceptA(c); // okay

function acceptB(b: B) {
  acceptA(b); // okay
}
```

Here, `A` and `B` have different declaration sites and different names, and `c`'s type is inferred to be an *anonymous* type.  Yet the compiler has no problems when you pass `c` into `acceptA()`, nor does it care if you pass an arbitrary value of type `B` into `acceptA()`.  As far as the compiler is concerned, `A`, `B`, and `typeof C` are identical types.  They might be *displayed* differently, but they are not different types.

Because they are the same types, then it should not be possible in principle to write any type function `type F<T> = ...` such that `F<A>` and `F<B>` and `F<typeof c>` result in any different type.  If you want `DynamicPropertyName<A>` to produce a type containing the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html) `"A"` but `DynamicPropertyName<B>` to produce a type containing `"B"` instead of `"A"`, then what you are looking for would violate structural typing and is therefore impossible.

Well, uh... it *sometimes* happens that the compiler does produce types that violate structural typing, but these are edge cases and you can't rely on them.  When something is supposed to be unobservable and you manage to observe it, you are essentially tricking the compiler into exposing some internal implementation detail, which might possibly change.  I'm thinking of [converting unions to tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type) or [trying to infer values for unused type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65304800/inference-of-generic-type-argument-of-class-fails-depending-on-properties-on-tha) in particular.  You can sometimes tease hidden information from the compiler, but what you get is undefined behavior, not a solution to a problem.

---

Now class names are a little different, since class constructors sometimes [do have a `name` property at runtime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#function_names_in_classes).  But you can't rely on that property being anything in particular at runtime.

There's [microsoft/TypeScript#43325](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43325) asking for more strongly typed `name` properties of `class`es.  If this were in place you might be able to do this for `class Foo`.

But even if you could 100% guarantee that `Foo.name` at runtime would be `"Foo"`, there are reasons in TypeScript not to expose this at the type level.  If `class Foo` had a static `name` property of type `"Foo"`, then `class Baz extends Foo {}` would presumably have a static `name` property of type `"Baz"`, right?  But then  `typeof Baz extends typeof Foo` would be false, and if class instance types had strongly typed `constructor` properties, then *`Baz extends Foo` would be false*.  It would be unpleasant if writing `class Baz extends Foo {}` would result in a type `Baz` that does not extend `Foo`.  All for a strongly-typed name property.  So it's not likely ever to happen.

---

Okay, so.  The compiler doesn't care that `Foo` is named `Foo` or that `Bar` is named `Bar`. And to play nice with TypeScript, you really shouldn't care either.  The fact that you seem to want this might indicate that you have [an XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  You have some underlying use case that you thought might be solved if you can get the compiler to spit out `"Foo"` for type `Foo` and `"Bar"` for type `Bar`.  Since this is not possible, you might want to step back and examine your use case again.

If you want the string literal types `"Foo"` and `"Bar"` to appear somewhere, you might want to put them in your code to begin with:

```
class Foo {
  fooProp = 123
  readonly myName = "Foo"
}

interface Bar {
  barProp: string;
  myName: "Bar";
}
```

Here you are explicitly adding strongly-typed names as a `myName` property.  Once you do this, you can access these names:

```
type DynamicPropertyName<T extends { myName: string }> = 
  { [K in T["myName"]]: any };

type WithPropFoo = DynamicPropertyName<Foo>; // {Foo: any}
type WithPropBar = DynamicPropertyName<Bar>; // {Bar: any}
```

You might feel that this is redundant, but remember that structural typing means it's not.  The type name `Bar` is irrelevant, and `interface Qux {barProp: string myName: "Bar"}` is identical to `Bar`, so if you care about having the name `"Bar"` it has nothing to do the declared name of the interface.

Maybe this doesn't work for your underlying use case, but the point is that you will need to achieve those goals some other way.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7IB4C5kDOYUoA5sgL4BQoksiKAQpjvkSSOdQgPYhHIEyALws8yAEQALCABtZPCZQDcVAPRrBfAQnxZx7MssrIqVGAFcQCMMD7JESAA5hUACjj5UAShbVHEC7uCN7GGsg8ANZwAJ5mlta29gEujG4ARviMvhhUyA4Izq4ZocjhUbFU1FQIsnAEBMgAYjw8mHnIMK0AClA8TiLIAIwATADMHVAQcAAmfLIxyAC2MQBycEsoohItilU04NDwSMiMcFDt+ennvf1sxEYdK+ub+BJnUBKq1WAxTigAERiIA2wAQt3+UF+LwgAB4ACrICDYSAgGaNLDPDYQe4cLgAPkGWAA2gBpZCgZDw4kSLGbCQAXQZ+DgIEWFFUVF+-2QAHVgGApBDdoMgSClmCIdBodjYbt8WFNBhdiy2dRuSh+YKIR9RcDQeC+pCZZtYR8FWUlR9VTFqkA)

Comment: Basically, my prediction was that if I can elaborate this, I will be able to implement the dependent property https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949513 but with `class`, not `type`, as I use TypeORM where I have to use classes

Comment: I have a field, say `type` which is `enum`, and I have another field, say, `obj` which is of type Foo, if `type === 'Foo'`, and Bar if `type === 'Bar'`...

Comment: Without a [mcve] of what you're talking about it's hard to know what to suggest, but `class`es cannot themselves implement a union.  You could presumably make the class generic, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nd4O0N), but again, I'd need to see a complete example with criteria for success and failure.  And probably this should be a different question since it's out of scope for this one as asked.  Good luck!

Comment: I understood that it probably impossible to do what I wanted. This is MRE https://tsplay.dev/wXkgJW Anyways, thank you for your help